# Why is my Rails App Processing as JS and */*

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I was recently watching the logs for my Rails 4 application and noticed it was processing the `show` action as JavaScript and `*/*`.

`Processing by ArticlesController#show as */*`

`Processing by ArticlesController#show as JS`

I am having a very hard time figuring out what this means. Is this cause for concern? I would assume it should only process as HTML.

Here is my show:

```
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @related = Article.where.not(id: @article.id).tagged_with(@article.tag_list, :any => true).take(4)
    @most_popular = Article.where.not(id: @article.id).order(impressions_count: :desc).take(50).sample(8)
    @feedback = @article.feedbacks.build
    impressionist(@article, :unique => [:session_hash])
    @articles = Article.where.not(id: @article.id).order(updated_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page]).per_page(12)
end
```

Comment: How do you hit the show action from browser ?

Comment: www.mysite.com/articles/:id -- it is the show page for the various articles on my site @Arup

Comment: @Kathan you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually set the response types for an action by adding a respond_to block in your action more info [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to)

add this at the end your show action and let me know if its working as intended, thanks.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
```

Comment: How does it determine which response type to choose when that block is not in place? @sghosh

Comment: their is this field **Content-Type** in request header , using that I guess you can check it in your controller using request.format or request.content_type